# Gut Hub API access token не действителен, в чем проблема?

Tags: github-api

Всем привет, возникла проблема с продолжительностью "жизни" access токена git hub api, при его создании, указывал его срок действия как "no expiration", но через определенный момент времени: час, два, три - он переставал быть действительным, и все запросы, возвращали ошибку 401, Bad credentials.

Comment: Так вы исчерпали лимиты, отдохните пару часиков, и снова заработает.

Comment: Не пользовался токеном с прошлого вечера, но он не работает. В документации к git hub api я прочел, что токен доступа, созданный для публичного репозитория с конкретно указанными правами доступа, будет отозван, возможно проблема в этом.